# spark.read parquet into a dataframe gives null values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm new in PySpark and long story short:
I have a parquet file and I am trying to read it and use it with SPARK SQL, but currently I can:

1. Read the file with schema but gives NULL values - spark.read.format
2. Read the file without schema (header has first row values as column names) - read_parquet

I have a parquet file "locations.parquet" and

```
location_schema = StructType([ 
StructField("loc_id", IntegerType()), 
StructField("descr", StringType())
```

])

I have been trying to read the parquet file:

```
location_df = spark.read.format('parquet') \
        .options(header='false') \
        .schema(location_schema) \
        .load("data/locations.parquet")
```

Then I put everything into a Temp table to run queries:

```
location_df .registerTempTable("location")
```

But after trying to run a query:

```
query = spark.sql("select * from location")
query.show(100)
```

It gives me NULL values:

[image]

The parquet file is correct since I have been running successfully this:

```
great = pd.read_parquet('data/locations.parquet', engine='auto')
```

But the problem with read_parquet (from my understanding) is that I cannot set a schema like I did with spark.read.format.
If I use the spark.read.format with csv, It also runs successfully and brings data.

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Parquet files include a schema already. Why do you want to use your own? Also, they don't have headers

Comment: I'm guessing that you're using your own schema in order to save time when loading the data (schema merging and evaluation). These things usually happen when the specified schema does not match the loaded one. Can you please load it without specifying a custom schema (with select if you insist) and print its schema? Just to verify your loaded data.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank you for your feedback. In that case, using the df.to_parquet, how can I use my schema as a parameter? Should I make all the necessary changes in the dataframe before?  And how can I have ensure that the temp tables have a schema?   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html

Comment: I don't understand the question. Pandas is not Spark.

Comment: @Nir Hedvat, you are correct, the spark.read.format('parquet') without the .schema brings all the data with select but of course 1st row is a header.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I mean. when I create the parquet file (in a different place), I use the DataFrame.to_parquet. That gives the parquet file all the information from dataframe? What if I need a different schema when reading the parquet?

Comment: Parquet is a column-oriented data storage format. It doesn't have rows (as opposed to Avro/CSV) and it does not contain a header (not in the sense that you're talking about). Can you please load it and print the schema?

Comment: Pandas already knows the schema when you create the file, yes. If you only need certain columns, then I'd suggest doing that after you read the file, not immediately via a schema definition

Comment: @NirHedvat location_df.schema gives me : StructType(List(StructField(862,LongType,true),StructField(Animation,StringType,true)))

Comment: @OneCricketeer ok, then the main problem is probably the creation of the parquet and not the reading process. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1):

> `location_df.schema` gives me : `StructType(List(StructField(862,LongType,true),StructField(Animation,StringType,true)))`

You have a Struct with *an array*, not just two columns. That explains why your first example is null (the names/types don't match). It would also throw errors if you starting selecting `loc_id` or `descr` individually.
It appears that the field names within the array of Structs are `862` and `Animation`, too, not the fields you're interested in

You can download a `parquet-tools` utility separately to inspect the file data and print the file schema without Spark. Start debugging there...

If you don't give the Spark reader a schema, then that information is already interred from the file itself since Parquet files include that information (in the footer of the file, not the header)